# Sending the gps data from the tracker to python server using socket

Tags: python, sockets, websocket, gps, iot

I am relatively new to python socket programming. We have a gps tracker ST-901 in which the ip and port can be specified for sending gps data.
A python socket server script was created in local machine(connected to wifi router) and the server was meant for listening to the incoming connections from the gps tracker. But the script is not receiving any data.

Say, the router's public ip is 10.175.31.48
The local machine is connected to this router. With the port number 5013, the connections should be sent to this local machine using port forwarding.

Also we set the ip and port address of the tracker as same as the router.

```
 import socket;


import sys;
import h2o;


s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM);
print "Socket created successfully";
port=5013;
s.bind(('',port));
print "socket binded to port %s" %(port);
s.listen(5);
print "socket is listening";
print socket.gethostname();
try:
        c,addr=s.accept();
        print "got connection from",addr;
        c.send('thank you connected');
        c.send("how are you")
        data=c.recv(1024);
        print data;
finally:
    c.close();
```

I am unable to receive gps data. Pls help...

Comment: Have you configured this router for Port Forwarding? To let the external data reach  your desired machine?

Comment: Yes..i have configured my router. whenever any sockets coming to port 5013 which is forwarded to my local computer. I can also connect to this ip and port from other computers and mobile phone.

Comment: 10.175.31.48 is non routable ip thus the tracker may not be able to connect to your python server.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your static ip or real IP

`s.bind(('192.168.2.175',port))`